# Changing cisco WiFi access point password

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a Cisco WiFi access point that is sharing a TPLink routers internet. The TpLink router has Microtic routerOS on it and I don't have it's password. I want to change Cisco access points password. Is it possible to change it without having routers password?

I can't find access point ip address. The default gateway returns 192.168.2.1 that is routers ipv4.

Comment: Does the TPLink router belong to you? If so then just press and hold the reset button to reset to factory default. Also, are you talking about the password to connect, or the password to log in to the control interface? The model numbers of both the Cisco and TPLink would also be helpful.

Comment: I need to change the password to connect and I don't want to factory reset, and Cisco model number is `wap4410n`.

Comment: OK, in that case you can run an IP scanning tool to figure out the IP address of your access point. Advanced IP Scanner should work http://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/

Comment: I used this tool and it is not return any IP address related to access point. Just all connected devices and routers IP address.